# The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows Defender Service

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, locked-files

I was trying to move a file from my **Downloads** folder to another folder, but I received the following message:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows Defender Service

I have never used or opened Windows Defender Service, so I'm not sure how to free up this file or how to get this file to move successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention that the file is coming from your **Downloads** folder, it is most likely in the middle of being scanned by Windows Defender. Depending on the file size, this shouldn't take more than a few minutes.

Waiting a couple minutes and trying again is probably the best way to resolve your issue without making your system unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to drag and drop the file into the recycle bin.  This has worked for me on the problem every time.  I am no expert, but this has worked for me.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to make a copy of the file in the downloads folder. This can be done while Defender is keeping the lock. Then Defender can finish its scan and at same time you can use the copy of the file. There is some risk to doing this, but at least Defender can notify you if the file is bad.